# don't know about couchdb connector for model index per Database in lb4

Tags: loopback4

wondering using lb4 and CouchDB with model-specific-configuration?

Any example code, please?

https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-connector-couchdb2#model-specific-configuration

thanks

Answer (score 0):

as new loopback 4 @model() accept jsonSchema to customize the JSON.

https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/Model.html#definition-of-a-model

the answer is

```
@model({
settings: {
"couchdb": {
  "modelIndex": "Tasks", // add Tasks key and value as model reference 
  "modelSelector": { "custom_selector": "user" },
  "database": "task" // will using same connection string 
   },
 }
})
```

however, I have no idea what is, I am new to lb4

`"modelSelector": { "custom_selector": "user" },`